# How to display content of the Word Document in a Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am working on a contract module in package. As you all know contract for diffreant companies are diffrent, I mean their logo, their way of data representation etc.

So I am createing a vf page which shows contract details to user. 
How can I create a vf page that can change its content.

I am thinking of saving an word file of contract and then reading it in visualforce page.

**Visualforce Page**

```
    <apex:page controller="UploadDocumentController" >
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Resume" />
                 <apex:outputPanel > 
                  <div class="requiredInput">
                    <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                      <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment1Blob}" /><br/>  
                      <div class="note"> doc, docx, txt, and pdf. Max 800 KB </div>

                  </div>
                </apex:outputPanel>
           </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!tempString}"></apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class UploadDocumentController {
transient public Blob attachment1Blob {get;set;}
public String tempString  {get;set;}
    Public void save(){
         Document resume = new Document();
         tempString= EncodingUtil.base64Encode(attachment1Blob);
         system.debug('##'+tempString);
         resume.body = attachment1Blob;
         resume.name = 'test';
         resume.Folderid = UserInfo.getUserId();
         insert resume;

    }
}
```

I have tried this but getting a long string as 0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAtgAAAAAAAAAAEAAAuAAAAAEAAAD+////AAAAALQAAAC1AAAA//////////////// in output

How can I read the content of visualforce page and display in visualforce page.
Also how can I embed my values from controller to visualforce page.

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: conga composer has a solution for generating sfdc data into word documents from a button click

Comment: Please help need solution without using any third party apps.

Comment: What is the use case? What you are really trying to achieve? Do you want to generate a word doc from SFDC data? Do you want your users to modify that document and commit the changes in SFDC? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I am trying to get content from user. User will give an word file or a doc which will have data. I will get that data and add to my visualforce page. But my question is how will i take this doc or pdf file and add it to visual force page?

Comment: if an overhead is acceptible your users can probably save the document as a word xml and then upload that to your application which can parse this xml and extract the data.

Answer (score 5):

So, basically you need ability to read doc file then update the doc file with some content from SFDC. To do this you need some sort of API/COM component to interact with doc file. As of now there is no such API/COM component available on force.com     Due to this, it is not feasible to READ/UPDATE doc file on force.com platform. So the only option to you is either use 3rd party solution like
conga composer or develop your own service using .net(or some other programming language) and consume that service from SFDC.

Answer (score 0):

//Simple Custom Controller to Insert an Attachment into Salesforce

```
public  class AttachmentUploadController 
{
    public String parentId {get;set;}
    public Attachment attach {get;set;}
    public string caseid{get;set;}
    public AttachmentUploadController()
    {
        attach = new Attachment();
    }

    //When user clicks upload button on Visualforce Page, perform upload/insert
    //Redirect user to newly inserted document
    public ApexPages.Pagereference upload()
    {

        //This shows how to insert an Attachment
        attach.ParentId = CaseId;
        insert attach;


        return new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(attach).view();   
    }
}
```